# Bypass AWS API Gateway quota on API keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

AWS API Gateway has [a hard limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#:%7E:text=API%20keys%20per,10000:%7E:text=API%20keys%20per%20account%20per%20Region) on the number of API keys as 10k. That limits the number of users of my API to 10k.
So if my API becomes popular I have to leave AWS API Gateway and use its competitor.
What do I miss?

Comment: Maybe AWS idea is not to use API keys when you're a popular service and use OAuth instead with auth ping-pong on client side.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that AWS has a habit of placing hard limits on managed services to prevent noisy neighbours (Like in DynamoDB RCU and WCUs) from disrupting other tenants of this services. Thus, the limit we have for API gateways.

Having huge traffics and requiring lots of API keys is a good business challenge to have (After all it means business is doing well), if your API starts hitting the hard key count limits, you may want to consider building your own application-level implementation of API keys.

This brings the following pros with it:

- API key is now shareable between multiple API gateways.
- Your application can now support more than 10K API keys
- If you decide to use other API gateways in the future or migrate to another cloud provider, this tailored solution is going to be compatible with those setups and won’t require force expiry of API keys (this is pretty bad experience for your consumers)